# What can be used instead of on_delete CASCADE

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I created a books app, It has Publisher and Books models. In books Model, I assigned a foreignkey for Publisher using `on_delete=models.CASCADE`. Actually I don't want to use this `on_delete` function, because if I delete data from parent table it will delete data on child table also. But I am getting:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

If I don't use `on_delete = models.CASCADE`.

Model:

```
class Book(models.Model): 
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 30) 
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author) 
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete = models.CASCADE) 
    publication_date = models.DateField() 

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

Comment: show your codes, only asking question wont solve it, you need to provide relevant information for people to help you,

Comment: class Book(models.Model):
 title = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
 authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
 publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
 publication_date  = models.DateField()

 def __str__(self):
  return self.title

Comment: add that to the question and show the stacktrace

Comment: You can set `on_delete=models.SET_NULL`. This will Set the ForeignKey null. Read more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Answer (score 0):

As of Django 2.0 the `on_delete` is [required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0).  There are several options you can provide for `on_delete`, they are detailed [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete).

Answer (score 0):

It is mandatory to add on_delete function from Django V2.0, So you can set (tablename, on_delete = SET_NULL, blank  = True, null = True). if u don't want to delete data from child table when parent data is deleted.

> publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, models.SET_NULL, blank = True, null = True)